# Trying to create chartjs constructor

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization

I have two functions, one that gets data, and another that creates the chart. This works fine. Now I want to move the second function into a constructor, but I can't get the data to display, just an empty line chart. what am I missing?

Thanks

```
let data = getData() // returns arrays xs and cbrv

class BuildChart {
    constructor() {

        console.log(data) // <-- as expected
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart')

        this.newChart = new Chart (ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: data.xs, // 
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        labels: "cbrv",
                        data: data.cbrv
                    }],
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getData() {
  return {
    a: [{ x: 118, y: 92.82 }, {x: 115.8, y: 92.88 }, {x: 113.03, y: 93.62 } ],
    b: [{ x: 218, y: 92.82 }, {x: 215.8, y: 92.88 }, {x: 213.03, y: 93.62 } ]
  };
}
var data = getData();

class BuildChart {
    constructor() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                  {
                      label: 'Example',
                      showLine: true,
                      backgroundColor: 'red',
                      data: data.a
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Example 2',
                      showLine: true,
                      backgroundColor: 'green',
                      data: data.b
                  }
                ]
            }
        });
    }
}

new BuildChart();
```

```css
canvas { max-width: 400px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: That works, but I'm returning multiple arrays and w/o the constructor I've been able to reference them via i.e. `data.xs` and `data.cbrv`. Each of these arrays is a separate chartjs data object i.e. `data: data.cbrv` }, { data: data.xs }, `.... each with its own label, fill, bgcolor etc...   Make sense? Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've edited my answer to show multiple datasets from the function call.

Comment: Ok I think my underlying problem now is that I'm using an async function to get the data, but I don't know how to properly use its return value from inside the constructor.  In my previous graphing function, I just did `const data = await getData()` and it worked, but this isn't working for me with a constructor. Thanks again.